# Connect to two DB using Oracle wallet without TNS_ADMIN path change

Tags: java, oracle, sqlplus

```
-bash-4.1$ export TNS_ADMIN="/tmp/PKI/DB_A"
-bash-4.1$ sqlplus /@DB_A
```

Connects fine

```
-bash-4.1$ export TNS_ADMIN="/tmp/PKI/DB_B"
-bash-4.1$ sqlplus /@DB_B
```

Connects fine

```
-bash-4.1$ sqlplus /@DB_A
```

Error logon denied (since the last TNS_ADMIN path points to the DB_A)

There is an option of using TNS Names with the JDBC, i.e. set the oracle.net.TNS_ADMIN property to the directory that contains your tnsnames.ora file ( java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin).

The situation is, I will not be able to change TNS_ADMIN Path. Is there any option in Oracle sqlplus *NOT* to specify TNS_ADMIN path but seemlessly connect to both DB_A and DB_B ?

Comment: why you can not change TNS_ADMIN? Is you question about sqlplus or about JDBC? On Unix there is also users local file `~/.tnsnames.ora`. So you can make it a symbolic link and you can change its target by using `ln -sf`. PS: AFAIK Oracle wallet implements the same interface as Java keytool. So you can use it as Java keystore. The sqlplus logon is just one of the usages.

Comment: Hi ibre, The situation is, I will not be able to change TNS_ADMIN Path. Is there any option in Oracle sqlplus NOT to specify TNS_ADMIN path but seemlessly connect to both DB_A and DB_B ?

Comment: I do not think so. Maybe you can create a dblink from DB_A into DB_B - but this really is not a solution. Either you have also shell access and then you can change env. variables or it's between you and sysadmins. If they made such a restriction then they should find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to DB like this:

```
sqlplus /@"(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.10.10.10)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER= DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DB_A)))"
```

i.e. copy the full text from the `tnsnames.ora` file you like to use. Remove any line breaks for use on command line.